# AWS JSON syntax error wherever a comma follows curly bracket

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I'm following [this](https://d1.awsstatic.com/Getting%20Started/tutorials/securing-remote-access-mfa-session-manager-aws-sso.pdf?refid=gs_card) AWS tutorial. On page 46 where you add permissions to IAM role, the json code causes errors. The error is, `Ln 10, Col 1JSON Syntax Error: Fix the JSON syntax error at index 168 line 10 column 1,` wherever a comma follows curly bracket. Removing the comma and/or curly bracket doesn't work.

Here's the json I have:

```
 {
 "Sid": "describeLogGroups",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": [
 "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
 ],
 "Resource": [
 "arn:aws:logs:<us-west-2>:<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>:log-group:*"
 ]
},
{
 "Sid": "describeLogStreams",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": [
 "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
 ],
 "Resource": [
 "arn:aws:logs:<us-west-2>:<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>:log-group:*:log-stream:*"
 ]
},
{
 "Sid": "createLogStream",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": [
 "logs:CreateLogStream",
 "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
 ],
 "Resource": [
 "arn:aws:logs:<us-west-2>:<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>:loggroup:<SessionManagerLogGroup>:*"
 ]
},
{
 "Sid": "putEvents",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": [
 "logs:PutLogEvents",
 "logs:GetLogEvents"
 ],
 "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:logs:<us-west-2>:<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>:loggroup:<SessionManagerLogGroup>:log-stream:*"
 ]
},
{
 "Sid": "listBucket",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<session-manager-log-bucket123>"
},
{
 "Sid": "putObject",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": "s3:PutObject",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<session-manager-log-bucket123>/*"
}
```

What adjustments need to be made to fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `Version` and `Statement` portions of your policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "...",
            "Resource": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```